# How do I set the status code with custom message in asp.net core 2.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I am working on asp.net core version 2.1, I have created a sample API project which works fine but I am unable to modify the status code with a custom message for example:

In Postman:

> 200 OK

Expecting:

> 200 Custom_Message

The code that I tried:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
     Response.StatusCode = 200;
     Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = "Custom_Message";
     return Ok();
}
```

Postman's current Output:

[image]

[`GitHub Repository`](https://github.com/prashantpimpale93/aspnetcore2.1-api)

Comment: `return Content("Custom_Message")`

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov It appends that "Custom_Message" value in the body. I want that message to be displayed next to `200`

Comment: The code you've shown works for me.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Ok, in the screenshot: it display's `200 OK` and what I want `200 Custom_Message`. If that is what you are getting then feel free to post an answer

Comment: Here's a screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/9NHYj76/Postman.png.

Comment: @KirkLarkin That is what I want! Can you post the code in the answer?

Comment: It's the exact same code from your question so there's nothing for me to post. I guess there must be something else going on in your particular project.

Comment: Try creating a [mcve] or uploading a simple project to GitHub for others to look at.

Comment: @KirkLarkin any idea where do I need to check especially?

Comment: @KirkLarkin will add it

Comment: @KirkLarkin added here:https://github.com/prashantpimpale93/aspnetcore2.1-api

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov Have added GitHub repo with my code:https://github.com/prashantpimpale93/aspnetcore2.1-api

Comment: That works for me too. Are you performing a GET to `http://localhost:5000/api/Values` in Postman? What version of Postman do you have?

Comment: @KirkLarkin yes and Version 6.7.4

Comment: What endpoint are you using in postman to call your api?

Comment: `http://localhost:64031/api/values`

Comment: If you have Chrome, make the request in there and look at the developer tools. I see this: https://i.ibb.co/mt3SxPX/Chrome.png

Comment: @KirkLarkin checked in developers tool getting `200 OK` here:https://ibb.co/kKvmKVX

Comment: @KirkLarkin Now it worked for me. But for `200` status code is not working, showing 200 OK

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create your custom class:

```
public class CustomResult : OkResult
{
    private readonly string Reason;

    public CustomResult(string reason) : base()
    {
        Reason = reason;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ActionContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        context.HttpContext.Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = Reason;
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCode;
    }
}
```

Then in your controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
     return new CustomResult("Custom reason phrase");
}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I guess the problem is not the code then, since as it is reported in comments your code also works pretty good. Are you calling the right method? Also this is compatible with `.NET Core 2.1` so I can't figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: @ALPHA it's not working for only 200 when I use other than this like 201, 400 then custom messages is working!

Comment: You should change the inherit other than the status code. So if you, for example, want to use `400` as status code, you should change `: OkResult` with `: BadRequestResult`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Sorry I misread, so it's working for every status codes but not for 200? That's really weird

Comment: yup, exactly I m also unable to understand why this is not working for 200

Comment: That line helped me in another solution: "        context.HttpContext.Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = Reason;
"

Answer (score 0):

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public abstract class BaseApiController : ControllerBase
{
    public override OkResult Ok()
    {
        return base.Ok();
    }

    public override OkObjectResult Ok([ActionResultObjectValue] object value)
    {
        return base.Ok(new Response
        {
            Result = value,
            Status = ResultStatus.Success,
            Message = string.Empty
        });
    }
}
```